# URL Shortener for high traffic website

Tags: url-shortener, short-url

we have a high traffic website with the 500K daily sessions and at least  6 million contents ( and our growth is 1 million monthly), we're using *goo.gl* shortener system, but we've decided to setup ours,( in-house shortener system).

I've searched for shortener opensource systems and also I'd worked with [YOURLS.ORG](https://yourls.org/) in the small and medium project but I'm not sure it could work with high scale/traffic website, So What do you suggest us?

**FYI**: our website is based on PHP + MYSQL (but we could treat it as a micoro service in our system and it could be written in any language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this application.

[snaker](https://github.com/erishforG/snaker). This application is based on django2 and python3.

I used this application using for more than 500K users with loadbalancer and 2 instances on EC2.